# Mysql: как правильней организовать необязательную связь полей в таблицах

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, индексация

Есть 2 таблицы `queries` и `orders`. Поле `orders.query_id` связано с полем `queries.id` через внешний ключ, но эта связь не является обязательной, то есть, `orders` не обязательно должен быть связан с `queries`, например когда пользователю начисляются бонусные баллы за первую регистрацию создается запись в `orders`, но она не привязана к конкретному запросу в `queries`.

[image]

В данном случае, нельзя создать запись в `orders` если нет соответствующей записи в `queries`. Как поступить в этом случае с индексацией `query_id` в таблице `orders`?

- Нужно ли убирать индекс?
- Нужно ли добавить в `queries` дефолтную
  строку, например с `id=0`  как раз для таких случаев?
- Или вообще
  убрать "явную" связь в базе данных и оставить только программную?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если запись в orders ни к чему не привязана, то оставляйте поле query_id не заполненным, т.е. равным NULL. (для этого при объявлении поля оно должно быть объявлено как допускающее NULL значения). Больше ничего делать не надо. Ключ не мешает существованию записей с NULL. Индексы так же никак не влияют.

Comment: Спасибо, ровно то, что нужно